Can four integer numbers $x$, $y$, $x-y$, $x+y$ be powerful numbers where $\gcd(x,y)=1$?
Can four integer numbers $x$, $y$, $x-y$, $x+y$ be powerful numbers where $\gcd(x,y)=1$ ?

Heuristically the probability of this should be at least $\frac{1}{\max(x,y)^2}$, and the sum of this diverges, so I'd expect infinitely many examples. Have you tried a computer search? To what limit?

There are no solutions with $x + y \leq 10^8$, so the heuristic argument might be incorrect. Mod 4 we can see that one of $x, y$ must be divisible by 4 and the other odd. Are there any other such conditions?

It isn't known if there exist three consecutive powerful numbers, so even if you set $y = 1$ you can't get a negative answer without solving that open problem. Does the abc conjecture (or maybe n conjecture) imply anything for this question, like it does for the case of $y=1$?

If we use the abc conjecture with $a = (x - y) (x + y), b = y^2, c = x^2$ then $\operatorname{rad}(abc) \leq \operatorname{rad}(a) \operatorname{rad}(b) \operatorname{rad}(c) \leq x \sqrt{y x}$, so for any $0 < \varepsilon$ there are only finitely many solutions with $y = O(x^{1 - \varepsilon})$

@DanielWeber Oh, let $y=1$, this question degenerate to Can three consecutive numbers be powerful?

I have just checked, there are no solution for first 10000 powerful number ($x+y \le 23002083$).

@DanielWeber abc doesn't imply finitely many solutions, check my answer with infinitely many solutions.

@joro I only said it implies finitely many solutions with $y = O(x^{1-\varepsilon})$ for $0<\varepsilon$.

Using the infinitely many rational points on the curve
$x^4-y^4=(2^4-1) y^2 z^2$, the smallest solution we found
is with $x$ having 146 decimal digits (smaller solutions may exist).
Using the same curve, there are infinitely many solutions of
very large size.
The solution in sage code:
def fourpowerful1():
    """
    
    x^2,y^2,x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2 all powerful
    Coming from the infinitely many points on the curve 
    x^4-y^4=(2^4-1) y^2 z^2
    Author:  Georgi Guninski, Thu Jul  4 10:21:11 AM UTC 2024
    """
    x_1=51203929262112985953504884979884461019907289047719199306830900384193163023961621160885389604169689049920413633464220309380754803019095566545430404
    y_1=5168374460623477253206993537636619974630340154166825903559471772312195920181455373026653181235106737210693085904835681664925203352727316123710721
    tp=x_1+y_1
    tm=x_1-y_1
    print("gcd=",gcd(x_1,y_1),x_1.is_square(),y_1.is_square(),(tp//5^3).is_square(),(tm//3^3).is_square(),"digits(x)=",len(str(x_1)) )
    print("x=",factor(x_1))
    print("y=",factor(y_1))
    print("x+y=",factor(tp))
    print("x-y=",factor(tm))


I think there are infinitely many solutions via rational points on elliptic curves, but the smallest solution is large.
Let $X=x^2,Y=y^2$, then we want $(X^2-Y^2)*(X^2+Y^2)=X^4-Y^4 =\text{powerful}$
In this question Elkies gave solution to similar problem $X^4+Y^4=\text{powerful}$:
$427511122^4 + 1322049209^4=\text{powerful}$
Let $a_1,a_2,a_3$ be integers.
The projective curve $X^4-Y^4=a_1^3 (a_1 X+a_2 Y)^2 Z^2$ is genus one elliptic curve and it may have infinitely many points $(X,Y,Z)$ and I believe it may have infinitely many solutions with $(X,Y)$ coprime.
Someone may try to find points on the elliptic curve for some $a_i$.
Comment appears to suggest that abc implies finitely many solution,
but I believe abc doesn't imply this.
As pointed by Peter Taylor, solutions to $X^4-Y^4=\text{powerful}$ exist
like $10113607^4-4319999^4$, but in this particular case
$X^2+Y^2$ is not powerful. It is a near miss and the only exponent
of one is at the oddest prime $2$.

In the same question, Elkies gives a solution to $X^4 - Y^4$ is powerful, but it's not a solution to this problem solely because $\nu_2(X^2 + Y^2) = 1$.

@PeterTaylor Indeed, you are right, this is a near miss of the oddest prime 2. Do you think my approach may work?

I don't have an intuition either way. Having infinitely many solutions is not sufficient because all of them might have the same obstacle with the stray 2, but it would be quite interesting if that were in fact the case.

@PeterTaylor I edited with solution of size 146 digits. You have sharp eye for bugs, would you please confirm or disprove it?

Your solution checks out.

A smaller example than joro's,
also obtained by the same elliptic-curve method, is
$$
x = 7776485^2, \quad
y = 6^3 439967^2, \quad
x+y = 10113607^2, \quad
x-y = 4319999^2.
$$
I found it by starting from the near-miss $(x,y,x+y,x-y) = (25,24,49,1)$
and tripling the corresponding point $(X,Y,Z) = (5,1,7)$ on the curve
$E_6: (X^2-6Y^2)(X^2+6Y^2)=Z^2$ to make $Y$ a multiple of 3.
The appearance of $10113607^2$ and $4319999^2$ means that
this solution could also have been obtained from the "near-miss"
involving $10113607^4 - 4319999^4$ in Peter Taylor's comment.
Again we get infinitely many further solutions using the group law on $E_6$.
P.S. To make it easier to check the above solution:
x = 7776485^2
y = 6^3 * 439967^2
x+y == 10113607^2
x-y == 4319999^2
P.P.S. (added later) Here's what "tripling the point" looks like.
I wrote $E_6$ as a curve in projective space with coordinates $X,Y,Z$
of weights $1,1,2$; setting $Y=1$ gives the affine curve
$C: x^4 - 36 = z^2$ with a rational point $P_1: (x,z) = (5/2,7/4)$.
We want a quadratic polynomial $Q(x)$ such that the graph of $z=Q(x)$
intersects $C$ at $P_1$ with multiplicity $3$; the fourth intersection
will be the desired "tripled" point $P_3$ (actually $P_{-3}$, but that point
serves the same purpose).  We get $Q$ by expanding $z$ in a Taylor series
about $x(P_1)$ to order 2:
$$
z = \frac74 + \frac{125}{7} \Bigl(x - \frac52\Bigr)
            - \frac{27575}{7^3} \Bigl(x - \frac52\Bigr)^2 + \cdots
$$
We thus set $Q(x) = -7^{-3} (27575 x^2 - 144000 x + 187056)$.
Then $x^4 - 36 = Q(x)^2$ has the expected triple root at $x = 5/2$,
and we calculate that the remaining root is $7776485 / 2639802.$
That's the $x$-coordinate of a new pair of rational points on $C$.
The desired $X,Y$ are then the numerator and denominator of $x^2/6$.

Is your $E_6$ really a curve? It is in 3 variables and is not homogeneous. sage gives error when trying to construct a curve.

Yes, it is a curve in the weighted homogeneous space with X,Y,Z of weights 1,1,2.  That's what you get when you form the double cover of P^1 (with coordinates X:Y) branched at 4 points.

Thanks, I didn't know this. I suppose you did the group law on a Weierstrass model to which you mapped E_6?

No, I worked on E_6 directly.  I guess I should explain this in my answer . . .
Meanwhile, if you want to work with curves in ordinary projective space,
you can use the intersection of the two quadrics $X^2 \pm 6Y^2 = Z_\pm^2$
in 3-dimensional projective space with coordinates $X,Y,Z_+,Z_-$,
which is 2-isogenous with $E_6$.

I suppose you used Magma for the computations? Looks like sagemath doesn't support group law in such complications. I worked on $C : x^4-y^4=15 y^2 z^2$, went to the Weierstrass model, used the group law, went to $C$, cleared the gcd to get coprime solutions and then cancelled the squarefree part.

Not Magma.  I used Maxima, but it's basically polynomial arithmetic, and could have been done by Euler if not Fermat.

@NoamD.Elkies What is your email? can I get Your email to discuss some ideas. Hopefully, when discussing with him, we can build a general rule for equation with finite solutions. My email in next comment

My email: oaidt.evnpsc@gmail.com
